# how to write the code to make an exception for the non-disabled option in select field

Tags: php

Foremostly i'm bad at explaining things, if you don't understand the problem i'll explain it with time and comments,so be patient. Problem i'm facing is when  field is empty and its disabled value shows up,it shows the following error as it is not counted as empty.

```
    Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_gender.php
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPJqZ.jpg)

What i want is that when  value is empty and disabled value shows up, it should show an error 'gender field is not selected'.So how to write the php code for that!
```

````
```
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    echo"$gender";
    $role = $_POST['role'];
    echo "$role";
} ?>
<select name="gender">
    <option disabled selected value>Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Others</option>
</select><br><br>
<select name="role">
    <option disabled selected value>Role</option>
    <option>Author</option>
    <option>Admin</option>
    <option>Others</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
````

Look at the code above, if nothing is selected and it shows gender. It is not counting itself as empty as disabled value is there. So how to write the code to make an exception for the non-disabled option. What i basically want is if disabled value shows up and one clicks on submit button, it should show an error like "no option selected". If still not understood lets discuss in comments.
And i couldn't find similar questions any.

Comment: I know there are exceptional situations in which knowing the gender of somebody is required, but if that's not the case you could simply leave this out. Also, having to select "Others" when you don't feel like sharing your gender is, well, how to say it, "weird"? Why not: "Rather not say", or something similar.

Comment: One of the problems could be that your options have no `value` attributes. See: [PHP Select Option](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-select-option/) tutorial for a nice example with `filter_input()`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware did you understand my problem, hope you got it! i tried my best tho :P Okay i'll put rather not to say....but what to do if nothing is selected , it shows the "error   Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_gender.php", i want to display an error that no option is selected on that and restrict the page validation.

Comment: You can probably use `if (!isset($_POST['gender'])) { .... }` to check whether none of the gender options is selected.

Comment: if (!isset($gender)) {
   echo"<script>alert('Gender not selected!')</script>";
  }

Comment: it doesn't restrict the page from getting validated. it shows the same error too.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `$_POST['gender']` in other places, because it's not set.

Comment: Normally you would do: `if (<gender is set>) { <do things with gender> } else { <error message> }`.

Comment: i removed ...but it shows on selection too

Comment: Did you see my second comment?

Comment: if (isset($gender)) {
   $gender = $_POST['gender'];
   echo"$gender";
  }else{
   echo"<script>alert('Gender not selected!')</script>";
  }

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i've seen your second comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['gender']) and $_POST['gender'] != '') {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    } else {
        $gender = "Gender field is not selected";
    }
    echo"$gender <br/>";

    if(isset($_POST['role']) and $_POST['role'] != '') {
        $role = $_POST['role'];
    } else {
        $role = "Role field is not selected";
    }
        echo "$role <br/>";
} ?>
<select name="gender">
    <option disabled selected value>Gender</option>
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
    <option>Others</option>
</select><br><br>
<select name="role">
    <option disabled selected value>Role</option>
    <option>Author</option>
    <option>Admin</option>
    <option>Others</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sory there was a space on $_POST['role '] just remove it, i'll remove it and you can copy past and it will work

Comment: Yes working thanks.

Comment: what if we want to add else here? can you write the code in else/if format???

Comment: Check now if that exactly what you want